# urlencode() does not work

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a URL like this:

```
http://x.x.x.x/feedsms?to=$groupName&text=$content"
```

When I call this url it should send a SMS.
I have used `file_get_contents()` to read the SMS content and `urlencode()` because of the spaces and special characters:

```
$url = urlencode("http://x.x.x.x/feedsms?to=$groupName&text=$content");
$urlContent = file_get_contents($url);
```

The `$content` is something like this:

```
F: user@domain.com S: Veeam Repoting B: Target: y.y.y.y, Status: Error, Time: 8/22/2015 3:05:30 PM
```

But I can't call the url:

```
file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...
```

Also I used `rawurlencode()`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.urlencode.php) should be used, as docs says, to encode a string to be used **in a query part** of a URL. You should not use it on your entire URL but only for every parameter that should be encoded, in your case `$groupName` and `$content`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$url = "http://x.x.x.x/feedsms?to=" . urlencode($groupName) . "&text=" . urlencode($content);
```